# Calculate a Field including NA values in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have been wrestling with a problem where I needed to find the difference between two reports in the form of data frames. After much struggle with setdiff() and anti_join(), I finally found the starting point of what I want with full_join. I am creating the following UDF to compare the two files-

```
Compare <- function(dfV0,dfV1)
{

  Dataname <- intersect(names(dfV0),names(dfV1))


  Result <- full_join(dfV0,dfV1,by=subset(Dataname,Dataname!="Value"))

  Result <- Result %>% select(-Value.x,everything())  #Push column to the end

  Result <- Result %>% select(-Value.y,everything())  #Push column to the end

  rename(Result,
         Old_Values=Value.x,
         New_Values=Value.y)

  Result$Change <- "--"
  Result$Change <- Result$New_Values - Result$Old_Values


  }
```

A sample data set is given below-

[image: Report1]

[image: Report2]

It is possible that the number of rows may differ between the two, and it is possible that the entire data will be exactly identical to each other. Once I have the "Change" column, which I envision to have "NA" wherever there are missing data in the dataframes, I can use that to subset out newly added data, gone data, and value modified data, which are my final objective anyway. But for some reason, the lines with Result$Change is giving me error, saying that

`Error in`$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Change", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 4357
In addition: There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)`

Which is really annoying, since I know I have done the same thing in the past to get some NA's in my output column. And that was without the line where I predefine the column with "--" values. I do not want to put them to 0, because, as the saying goes, Na's are NA's. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Many functions in R, especially within `dplyr`, do *not* assign in place. That means calling `rename(x, blah = v1)` returns a data frame without changing anything about `x` unless you assign it somewhere. That makes this essentially a typo. Also, pictures of data aren't useful for helping you debug, since we can't load your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think rename modifies in place:

```
   Result <-  rename(Result,
             Old_Values=Value.x,
             New_Values=Value.y)
```

Comment: It does. I failed to mention this, but the dplyr package is installed and loaded as I am running this code.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. That would be highly unusual.

Comment: If you remove the last two lines, that is, the Result$Change lines, and rerun the function before using it, it does change the name. That much, I can see in my results.

Comment: Yes, but in that case it is returning the output of the rename function. It is not altering the Result variable.   You need to change Result.

Comment: `dplyr::rename(mtcars, new_var = cyl)` this returns a new data.frame but mtcars is unchanged.

Comment: @camille, @SmokeyShakers, I am sorry for the data image. I understand what you mean now. Because my output was showing me the modified name, I assumed that the name of the variable had changed. Apparently not. I made it work by calculating the change column first, and then renaming the columns by `Result<- rename(Result...)`. It is perfect now. Thank you!